# Add Records to Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

I want add Records to Core Data but error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

help me

```
let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext
let conchym = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Muoigiay", into: context)
conchym.setValue("date", forKey: "time10")
conchym.setValue("\(diemdung)", forKey: "dung10")
conchym.setValue("\(diemsai)", forKey: "sai10")
// save to data
do {
   try context.save()
} catch {
   print("Failed saving")
}
```

Comment: Please add the Exception Breakpoint to get more information about the exception. Are the `keys` spelled correctly? It's highly recommended to use `NSManagedObject` subclasses and dot notation, it avoids KVC errors.

Comment: Could it be that you're setting the "time10" field to the string "date" instead of an actual date object? Check the error message at the start of the console output, that should give you a better idea of what's actually going wrong.

Comment: thanks everyone i found the error due to the line:
let container = NSPersistentContainer (name: "name")
xcode cannot link to that "name"
in the project's Appdelegate file
because I added codedata after I created the project